# Struts 2 - JSP : Render String as JSP

Tags: java, string, jsp, struts2

I have an action class with a String property named `jspString`. I create the content for the resulting JSP of this action class using the property `jspString`. I have included my action class and the resulting JSP codes. My problem is, when I try to include a JSP page , using `jsp:include` tag, it is not rendering the content of that page in the resulting page.

**Action class :**

```
public class HomeAction extends ActionSupport
{ 
    private String jspString = "";
    public String execute()
    {
            jspString += "<div>";
            jspString += "<p>";
            jspString += "<jsp:include page=\"check.jsp\">";                                  
            jspString += "</p>";
            jspString += "</div>";
            return "success";
    }
    public String getJspString() 
    {
        return jspString;
    }

    public void setJspString(String jspString) 
    {
        this.jspString = jspString;
    }
}
```

**Resulting JSP:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<body>
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="jspString"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

now `div`, `p` tags are created. But `jsp:include` is not working. It is not displaying the contents of `check.jsp` in the resulting page.

Comment: where are you including your JSP? i am not able to see it in your code and how you are including it?

Comment: check your path for "check.jsp" and the request path that you made. Since there was already a request was made to server and so the mapping will be changed according to this request and so the "check.jsp" will not be in that directory. It is searching it in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `s:action` tag it allows execute action on the server and return jsp in the body of the tag.

```
<s:action name="home"/>
```

Comment: +1 for action tag, though not sure what OP want exactly.though we can use `executeResult`

Comment: Thank u all for ur replies. Actually i am creating the jsp page dynamically. I tried changing the path of "check.jsp". But jsp:include is not happening.

Comment: Roman can u pls tell me wer to use                                             <s:action name="home"/> this??